# Rest API throttle when filtering on look up column

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, threshold

I'm developing a custom sharepoint solution (SP 2016) where I'm retrieving data from a list with 5000+ items in it. In one of the API calls I'm trying to filter on a look up field where the list in which the look up is made in also has 5000+ items. When the list I'm querying has less than 5000 items it works without errors but as soon as it has more I get a  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException.

I know there is limit preventing people from making queries that return more than 5000 items but in my case the query would only return about 10.

Filtering on any other field works fine even when the list is 5000+ in size.

Are there further restrictions for filtering on look up fields compared to other field types?

The query:

```
"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('FIRMAMAPPER')/Items?top=100" +
        "&$select=id,FIRMANR/FIRMANR,FIRMANR/FIRMANAVN" +
        "&$expand=FIRMANR" +
        "&$filter=FIRMANR/FIRMANR eq " + ArbitraryNumber;
```

Comment: it would help to have a look at the query. If you're using something like <contains> you'd run into such a gap...

Comment: Try indexing the column used as filter in your query

Comment: @Celophysis Editited the post to include my query.

Comment: @AkshayRandive All the columns are indexed already, in both lists.

Comment: You missed a `$` before your `top` parameter. Otherwise your query works, at least in my env.

Comment: @Salah You're right. Just corrected it but I'm still getting  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException. As said in the post the query does work when my list is sub 5000 items. Only stops working when the list hits the view threshold.

Comment: I guess the expand parameter is retrieving all items within its inline request before the filter takes effect. What happens if you reduce the request parameter like "&$select=id,FIRMANR/FIRMANR" + "&$expand=FIRMANR/FIRMANR" + "&$filter=FIRMANR/FIRMANR eq " + ArbitraryNumber; ?

Comment: @Celophysis Same result unfortunately. After a bit more testing it seems that any filter on lookup values generates the same error if the list is over 5000+ items, even if the request would only return a few items. I think I found a work around though. If I first filter on something else to bring the request below 5000+ it works. So filtering like this: "filter=Id ge 0 and Id le 5000 and FIRMANR eq SomeNumber" works. I can then just do this recursively increasing the Id filters by 5000 each time until I hit the largest Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments I ended up solving this with a work around where I make sure to only query 5000 items or less at a time and then filter those items on the values I need. The process goes likes this:

1. Find the lowest Id and the highest Id in the desired list and calculate how many calls the request must be split into: `Math.ceil((highest-lowest)/5000);`
2. Create a loop with that many iterations and use a filter like this to get items recursively: `"$filter=Id ge " + lowestId+i*5000 + " and Id lt " + lowestId+(i+1)*5000 + " and (other filters)"`
3. Save the results of each iteration so they can be accessed afterwards.